# Why are leaves turning yellow in a recently propagated pothos

Tags: propagation

I recently propagated some cuttings from my golden pothos in a pot filled with soil. After few days the leaves and stems strated appearing yellow and frail. What could be the cause of it?

Comment: Do you mean you took cuttings a few days ago and are now trying to propagate them, or did the cuttings already have roots? Did you enclose the pot in either a plastic bag or a grow box/propagator with clear lid if they didn't have roots? Drought causes the symptoms you describe

Comment: A picture would be helpful.

Comment: The cuttings did not have roots. I cut some twigs from the nodes and put in cocopeat with vermi compost. I am watering the pot enough. Did not enclose in plastic bag.

Comment: I will post a pic. For now i have removed the yellow leaves